# Move with Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

I'm trying move a `PictureBox` with Drag And Drop. With my code, the `PictureBox` is cloned. But I need to be able to move it. How can I do this?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += pictureBox1_MouseDown;
    }
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var dragImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
            DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            DestroyIcon(icon);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnGiveFeedback(GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
    }
    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Bitmap))) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap));
        var pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap));
        pb.Size = pictureBox1.Size;
        pb.Location = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X - pb.Width / 2, e.Y - pb.Height / 2));
        this.Controls.Add(pb);
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);
}
```

Comment: If the code is too long to post, then it's too long for anyone to read. Narrow things down to the smallest piece of code the reproduces the problem.

Comment: All the code is importante. This is a code which only drag and drop the pictureBox. But the picturebox doesn't move, it is copied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new PictureBox, just update the location of the old one to the drop location.  That is, instead of:

```
protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap));
    var pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap));
    pb.Size = pictureBox1.Size;
    pb.Location = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X - pb.Width / 2, e.Y - pb.Height / 2));
    this.Controls.Add(pb);
}
```

just use this:

```
protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Location = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X - pictureBox1.Width / 2, e.Y - pictureBox1.Height / 2));
}
```

Comment: It works, but when I dragging the image, the image is in real size...I wanna in pictureBox size...How can I do this?

Comment: And how do I if I wanna 2 PictureBoxes?

Comment: To keep the image the same size, copy and resize the bitmap that's in the PictureBox and use that instead of pictureBox1.Image.

Comment: If you want to be able to drag more than 1 control in the same way, then you will need to 1) save the currently-being-dragged control in a class-level variable when the drag starts (in pictureBox1_MouseDown for example) and 2) move that control instead of just pictureBox1 in OnDragDrop

Comment: I have created picBox = (PictureBox)sender; then I know what pictureBox I wanna move :D

Comment: And how keep I the image the same size?

Comment: I can't test it now, but you should be able to just copy it to a new bitmap by using "var bmp = new Bitmap(16, 16, Graphics.FromImage(picBox.Image));".  I think that should create a 16x16px bitmap from the original image

Comment: `picBox = (PictureBox)sender;
                var dragImage = new Bitmap(picBox.Size.Width, picBox.Size.Height, Graphics.FromImage(picBox.Image));
                IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
                Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
                DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                DestroyIcon(icon);`

doesnt work..the image hide when I'm dragging

Comment: DoDragDrop(dragImage, DragDropEffects.Copy);

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you further then, as I'm not currently at a computer.  If you still can't figure it out, post another question here and I'm sure you'll find your answer quickly!

Comment: Ok (: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281315/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-move-picturebox-size-of-image-when-im-dragging

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22592/discussion-between-illdev-and-elmugrat)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension method that will do this for any WinForms control: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/178587/Draggable-WinForms-Controls?display=Print

Comment: thank for recommendation. as an author of that extension I'll just add a link to nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Control.Draggable/