# Drag and Drop move PictureBox- size of image when I'm dragging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a method which move the PictureBox when I Drag and Drop. But when I'm dragging the PictureBox, the image has the real size of image and I wanna that the image has the size of PictureBox

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            picBox = (PictureBox)sender;
            var dragImage = (Bitmap)picBox.Image;
            IntPtr icon = dragImage.GetHicon();
            Cursor.Current = new Cursor(icon);
            DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            DestroyIcon(icon);
        }
    }

protected override void OnGiveFeedback(GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
    }
    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Bitmap))) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {

        picBox.Location = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X - picBox.Width / 2, e.Y - picBox.Height / 2));
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the image to shrink to fit the picturebox?

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=179

Comment: @glace yes, I need shrink fit the picturebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var dragImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)picBox.Image, picBox.Size);
```

instead of

```
var dragImage = (Bitmap)picBox.Image;
```

(and maybe call Dispose on the temporary image later, but the GC will deal with it if you don't)

Comment: If the aspect ratio of image doesn't match the aspect ratio of the picture box you need to calculate the correct size yourself. Won't be adding that to my answer since jmrnet already has posted an answer including it. Feel free to switch over to him as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the image in your picture box is the full size image.  The picture box just scales it for display purposes but the `Image` property has the original-sized image.

So, in your `MouseDown` event handler you want to resize the image before using it.

Rather than:

```
var dragImage = (Bitmap)picBox.Image;
```

Try:

```
 var dragImage = ResizeImage(picBox.Image, new Size(picBox.Width, PicBox.Height));
```

Use something like this method to resize the image for you:

```
public static Image ResizeImage(Image image, Size size, 
    bool preserveAspectRatio = true)
{
    int newWidth;
    int newHeight;
    if (preserveAspectRatio)
    {
        int originalWidth = image.Width;
        int originalHeight = image.Height;
        float percentWidth = (float)size.Width / (float)originalWidth;
        float percentHeight = (float)size.Height / (float)originalHeight;
        float percent = percentHeight < percentWidth ? percentHeight : percentWidth;
        newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * percent);
        newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * percent);
    }
    else
    {
        newWidth = size.Width;
        newHeight = size.Height;
    }
    Image newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    using (Graphics graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
    return newImage;
}
```

**Image resize code from here:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191424/Resizing-an-Image-On-The-Fly-using-NET*